# Read plist value in Appfile

Tags: ios, fastlane

I want to change the selected scheme based on the value of plist entry

Contents of `Appfile`

```
def get_live_scheme_name()
  setting = get_info_plist_value(path: 'path-to-info.plist', key: 'settings')
  
  return setting == "value" ? "schemeA" : "schemeB"
end

for_lane :build_ad_hoc do
  apple_id "..."

  data[:configuration] = "Release"
  data[:export_method] = "ad-hoc"
  data[:scheme] = get_scheme_name()
end
```

Can I run arbitrary code in the Appfile ?